# User Login Verification

Tags: c++

The program is Working perfectly fine .. but in strings if i want to restrict my username to 8 characters what should i do ? ?

```
 cout  << "Enter your Username  it should have a maximum limit of 8 characters\n "  << endl; 
getline(cin, user, '\n');
```

i want here that it should restrict user for 8 characters .. if greater then 8 .. then it  should keep asking 
 user   (while loop ??)) until user enters characters less then 8 ..

Comment: Does the code function correctly? Are you just wanting a *code review*? Is there something specific you're wanting help with? It's not immediately obvious what your asking. It seems like the Code Review stack exchange might be more what you're interested in.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this book, but I doubt that it wants you to write anything like `mystrcmp` or `mystrcpy`.

Comment: proper indenting may also help identify problem areas, and also allows you to follow the flow better.

Comment: It tells you to "display the message 'ERROR'" which your code clearly does not do. It also tells you to give them three chances to log in, and you give them five. Does not meet requirements.

Comment: Voting to close, because you edited the question to be significantly different than the original, making all of the below answers appear off topic.

Comment: Agreed, you just deleted your entire question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int mystrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)

{

while (*s1==*s2)

{

if(*s1=='\0')

return(0);

s1++;

s2++; }

return 1;//return(*s1-*s2);

}
```

your int mystrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) was returning the difference b/w the ascii values of first non-matched chars in strings s1 and s2 and it isnt always 1 as your code supposed to.

A clean implementation of your code can be found here [ideone link](http://ideone.com/wUvwjB)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few confusions, notably between C++ strings and C strings.

Your `mystrcpy` function is an attempt to copy a C style string, but it's not necessary in C++. Here's how you do it in C++. Replace this

```
mystrcpy(new_user,user)
```

with this

```
new_user = user;
```

As you can see it's a bit easier to copy a C++ string than a C string. You can delete the `mystrcpy` function.

Similarly your `mystrcmp` function is an attempt to compare C strings. Again it's not necessary in C++. Replace this

```
f = mystrcmp(user2,new_user);
if (f==0)
{
    cout << "Successful Login!! \n "; 
}
```

with this

```
if (user2 == new_user)
{
    cout << "Successful Login!! \n "; 
}
```

Again you can see that comparing C++ strings is easier than comparing C strings. Again you can delete the `mystrcmp` function.

There a few other errors, in the logic, and some missing semi-colons, but I'll leave you do figure those out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty much all over the place. For instance:

1. You need to `#include <string>` if you're going to use `std::string`.
2. `cin >> a; if ( a == 1 )` - what if the user doesn't enter an integer at all? You'll be comparing the value of an uninitialized `int` to `1`, which puts you in undefined behavior land. You should check the return from `cin`, or at a minimum initialize `a`.
3. As John mentioned, you read in `std::string`s, and then attempt to treat them like C strings. Don't, just use `new_user = user` and `if ( user2 == new_user )`.
4. If the user doesn't `"Enter 1 to enter Signup Screen"` you take them to the signup screen anyway.
5. In your `mystrcmp()` function, you `return 0` if `*s1 == '\0'`, but you fail to check if `*s2 == '\0'`. This means two things - one, if `s2` is shorter than `s1`, then you're going out of bounds and invoking undefined behavior again, and two, if `s2` is longer than `s1` but begins with `s1` (e.g. if `s1` contains `"billy"` and `s2` contains `"billybob"`) then your function will say they are equal when they are not.
6. Also in your `mystrcmp()` function, this: `return(*s1-*s2)` will either always return `0` less the value of the element of `s2` with the same index as the last index of `s1`, or it'll invoke undefined behavior if `s2` is shorter, as already explained. Either way, it's almost certainly not something you want to return.
7. `mystrcpy(target,source)` is not a valid function definition. This function also only copies the first character of `source` to the first character of `target`.
8. When you loop following an incorrect entry, you check `if (f == 0)` and `if (f == 1)`, but you never set `f` during this loop, so no matter what the user enters, you'll always just be checking what the initial result was, regardless of what they enter next.